# Hide a Commit Revision from the SVN show log

Tags: tortoisesvn

How do I hide a commit revision from the SVN show log window?

Comment: I really doubt you can do that unless you are admin of the repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, unless you delete the revision as admin.

All commits are public to the authorized users for reading the repository.